# Lock display - no password is required to get back. Is it normal?

Tags: password, lock-screen, bug-reporting

I expect the system to require a password when I have locked the display using the menu in the up right corner. It requires a password in the lock screen to get back to desktop. But not always!!!

Settings: Blank screen delay 0 (never), automatic screen lock off, delay disabled, screen lock on, suspend on, show notifications on, lock screen off.

How to reproduce:

1. Lock display from up right corner menu
2. on lock screen press Ctrl+Alt+F1
3. on full screen terminal press Ctrl+Alt+F7
4. You're back on X screen and the system did not ask a password.

Do you notice the same? (EDIT: the step 2 is not required)

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and default window manager.

Comment: I'm on Wayland, and it doesn't work that way for me. I need to go to Ctrl + Alt + F2, and there is the proper password screen.

Comment: Check your Settings/Privacy -- the lock switch is separate from the blank screen timeout. Is it on?